# How to test closures with enzyme?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I need to test which value will return closure.
Example:

```
onCell = (index) => (row, rowIndex) => ({
    style: { fontWeight: 600 },
    ref: rowIndex === 0 && this.cellRef(index)
  })
```

I expect return will be

```
{ 
    style: { fontWeight: 600 },
    ref: null || this.cellRef(index)
}
```

Comment: What's `this`? And why are you capturing it in a closure? As it's written, there really isn't a way to test it independently of the code it's defined in...

Comment: You mean i can't check what will return independent function???? I just pass parameters in this func, without independent environment

Comment: It's not an independent function. It's a closure, that references a value (`this`) that is defined in the surrounding lexical scope, and is dependent on that value. If you passed the object with the `.cellRef` method as a parameter instead, then it would be.

Comment: So, what i gonna do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the object as a parameter to the outer function along with the index rather than using `this`. Then you can pass it a `jest.fn()` with the appropriate return values and ensure the result is what you want and that the function got called:

```
onCell = (obj, index) => (row, rowIndex) => ({
  style: { fontWeight: 600 },
  ref: rowIndex === 0 && obj.cellRef(index)
});
```

Then in the tests:

```
const mock = {
  cellRef: jest.fn(),
};

mock.cellRef.mockReturnValue(true);
const cb = onCell(mock, 5);
```

Etc, etc.